# Using ES register gives errors

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, cpu-registers

I am converting a program from EMU8086 environment to *NASM*. When assembling *NASM* gives these errors :

> system\kernel.asm:14: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>
> system\kernel.asm:20: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>
> system\kernel.asm:28: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

My code is:

```
    jmp start
    ;============================== 
    ;Draws a horiz and vert line
    ;==============================
    startaddr   dw  0a000h  ;start of video memory   
    colour  db  1
    ;==============================
    start:    
    mov ah,00    
    mov al,19    
    int 10h         ;switch to 320x200 mode  
    ;=============================  
    horiz:    
    mov es, startaddr       ;put segment address in es  *** 1st ERROR HERE!  
    mov di, 32000       ;row 101 (320 * 100)    
    add di, 75          ;column 76    
    mov al,colour          
    mov cx, 160         ;loop counter
    hplot:
    mov es:[di],al      ;set pixel to colour *** 2nd ERROR HERE!
    inc di          ;move to next pixel   
    loop hplot  
    vert:    
    mov di, 16000       ;row 51 (320 * 50)    
    add di, 160         ;column 161    
    mov cx, 100         ;loop counter   
    vplot:
    mov es:[di],al      ; *** 3rd ERROR HERE!
    add di, 320         ;mov down a pixel   
    loop vplot
```

I have marked the lines with the errors. Why doesn't this work in *NASM*?

Comment: `mov es, [startaddr]` `mov al, [colour]` + missing `hplot:`

Comment: The `hplot:` label isn't missing, it's just not indented differently from the code, making it a lot less readable.  The problem is `loop hplot:`.  The colon only goes on the label def, not reference.

Comment: @PeterCordes : That is correct. One observation I'll make is that the first version of the program presented actually had the `hplot:` label as part of comment on the line above (so technically it was missing). The OP did turn around and fix that problem. I am guessing Dirk probably saw the original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Alternative to Other Answers

Since *0xA000* is a constant, one can define it as such and then use it as an immediate value rather than a memory operand. In order for this approach to work you need to place the constant in an intermediate register and then move it to the segment register.

---

You can define *startaddr* as a constant (not a memory address containing the segment value). You can create constants (immediate values) by using **EQU**.  Change this line:

```
startaddr   dw  0a000h  ;start of video memory
```

to

```
startaddr   EQU  0a000h  ;start of video memory
```

Since you can't [MOV](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) an immediate value to *DS*, *ES*, and *SS* directly, you place the value into an intermediate register and then move it to the segment register. So this code:

```
mov es, startaddr       ;put segment address in es
```

Could be:

```
mov ax, startaddr
mov es, ax              ;put segment address in es
```

Note: If creating readable code, and you use the method above - I recommend renaming *startaddr* to *STARTADDR*. The convention of an all upper case identifier suggests to the reader it is a constant (immediate value) instead of a variable.

---

The other errors you have are related to a syntax difference between EMU8086 and NASM. These lines:

```
mov es:[di],al      ;set pixel to colour
```

and

```
vplot:
mov es:[di],al
```

Need to be written with the segment inside the square brackets. They should look like this:

```
mov [es:di],al      ;set pixel to colour
```

and

```
vplot:
mov [es:di],al
```

---

I highly recommend you read the [*NASM* documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html) about generating DOS *COM* and *EXE* programs

Comment: @rkhb : I actually considered that when I decided to provide an answer. It is very legal to do it (as you are allowed to move a memory operand to _ES_). I decided to show the typical way of defining a constant for the video memory address. Both ways work, but the typical idiom IMHO for what this code is doing is the way I presented it. So both do the same thing. I just avoid a memory variable holding a constant.

Comment: @rkhb wrote a comment (now gone) that suggested `mov es, [startaddr]` . Putting square brackets around the operand makes it a memory reference and would work with the OPs code. My comment was in response to that. Someone already provided an answer using that method, I chose a slightly different approach which is generally more typical (especially if the video memory address being used doesn't change)

Comment: I saw too late that it was answered by @user3144770 and deleted the comment. Sorry.

Comment: No problem @rkhb, but I think you had a valid comment to my answer nonetheless. What I failed to put in my answer was that I was offering an alternative to the other answer. I intend to modify my answer to make that clear, so I am thanking you for actually bringing it up in general.

Answer (score 4):

In NASM you have to use square brackets to retrieve the value at *startaddr*.

Write:

```
mov es, [startaddr]       ;put segment address in es
```

Also NASM expects you to write the segment override between these brackets:

```
mov [es:di],al      ;set pixel to colour
```

One additional error that NASM can't possibly detect for you is how you thought having retrieved the *colour* variable. You should also use **[]** here:

```
mov al, [colour]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no processor instruction to load `es` or `ds` directly. You have to load a data register, then move that to the segment register

```
mov ax,0A000h
mov es,ax
```